# Trying to call contract.query read using @polkadot/api-contract results in value bit error

Tags: polkadot-js, ink

I am trying to call a contract read which is deployed on the Azero smartnet using @polkadot/api-contract following https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract. Here is my current code.

```js
import { ApiPromise, HttpProvider } from "@polkadot/api";
import { ContractPromise } from "@polkadot/api-contract";

import { abi } from "./psp34-metadata";

const main = async () => {
  const wsProvider = new HttpProvider("https://rpc-smartnet.test.azero.dev/");
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

  const nftCollectionAddress = `5FoLoL5mYXpBwxJUMDo3tcwh5VTrzaz3LvbA4B7LiivjXV7C`;

  // Construct our Code helper. The abi is an Abi object, an unparsed JSON string
  // or the raw JSON data (after doing a JSON.parse). The wasm is either a hex
  // string (0x prefixed), an Uint8Array or a Node.js Buffer object
  const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, nftCollectionAddress);
  
  const value = 0; // only useful on isPayable messages

  const gasLimit = 3000n * 1000000n;

  const senderAddress = `5CXCzYooepihLkWNbFQ9VJieLSWgguTEPe6eWrDM8wAytCea`; // * My SubWallet address

  const tokenId = 1; // Token ID of NFT Im trying to read

  const { gasConsumed, result, output } = await contract.query[
    "psp34Traits::tokenUri"
  ](senderAddress, { value, gasLimit }, value);

  console.log({ gasConsumed, result, output });
};

main();
```

I create the ContractPromise and can console.log the various methods on contract.query, but when i try to call `psp34Traits::tokenUri` I receive the error

```
Enum(Err):: Enum(Module):: Struct: failed on error: u8:: u8: Input too large. Found input with 26 bits, expected 8
```

Here is the exact message method from the deployed contract in ink! I am calling from Node

```rust
#[ink(message)]
fn token_uri(
    &self,
    token_id: u64
) -> String {
    let value = self.get_attribute(Id::U8(0), String::from("baseURI").into_bytes());
    let mut token_uri = String::from_utf8(value.unwrap()).unwrap();
    token_uri = token_uri + &token_id.to_string() + &String::from(".json");
    return token_uri;
}
```

Here is also the full error log. Any tips to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

```
2022-06-01 01:12:05        RPC-CORE: call(callRequest: ContractCallRequest, at?: BlockHash): ContractExecResult:: createType(ContractExecResult):: Struct: failed on result: {"_enum":{"Ok":"ContractExecResultOk","Err":"ContractExecResultErr"}}:: Enum(Err):: Enum(Module):: Struct: failed on error: u8:: u8: Input too large. Found input with 26 bits, expected 8
/Users/user/Work/azero/polkadotjs/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs/create/type.js:70
    firstError = new Error(`createType(${type}):: ${error.message}`);
                 ^
Error: createType(ContractExecResult):: Struct: failed on result: {"_enum":{"Ok":"ContractExecResultOk","Err":"ContractExecResultErr"}}:: Enum(Err):: Enum(Module):: Struct: failed on error: u8:: u8: Input too large. Found input with 26 bits, expected 8
```

Comment: solution was gas limit needed to be -1 :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/contract-call-returns-error-found-input-with-28-bits-expected-8-polkadot-js

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contract.query` either to read a contract value or to get cost estimations for a contract transaction. Any contract dispatchable can be called via `query` to get the gas and storage deposit estimations before submitting the transaction.

Because there are no on-chain consequences for `query`, you can pass -1 as gas limit. This is not recommended for `contract.tx` where real costs can occur. In this case, you should use the `gasRequired` value returned by the query.